# Cordova error: "not a valid target for emulator"

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to select a specific emulator target but I'm getting an error even if I pick one from the list. See below.

```
-> % cordova emulate ios --list              
Available iOS Virtual Devices:
     iPhone-4s, 8.1
     iPhone-4s, 9.2
     iPhone-5, 8.1
     iPhone-5, 9.2
     iPhone-5s, 8.1
     iPhone-5s, 9.2
     iPad-2, 8.1
     iPad-2, 9.2
     iPad-Retina, 8.1
     iPad-Retina, 9.2
     iPad-Air, 8.1
     iPad-Air, 9.2
     iPhone-6, 8.1
     iPhone-6, 9.2
     iPhone-6-Plus, 8.1
     iPhone-6-Plus, 9.2
     iPhone-6s, 9.2
     iPhone-6s-Plus, 9.2
     iPad-Air-2, 9.2
     iPad-Pro, 9.2
     Apple-TV-1080p, tvOS 9.1
     Apple-Watch-38mm, watchOS 2.1
     Apple-Watch-42mm, watchOS 2.1

-> % cordova emulate ios --target "iPhone-6s, 9.2"
Error: iPhone-6s, 9.2 is not a valid target for emulator
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running: `-> % cordova emulate ios --target "iPhone-6s"` This should do the trick.